# azure queue trigger function pull from two different queues

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

How can I have a single azure queue trigger function connect to two different queues.

Having two bindings like this seems to break it:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "theQueueItem",
      "queueName": "main",
      "connection": "QUEUE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "theQueueItem",
      "queueName": "priority",
      "connection": "QUEUE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "durableClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

If possible I would like one queue to take priority over the other. Such that `main` would only send jobs to the function if `priority` was empty, otherwise it would take jobs from `priority` until empty.

Comment: You can definitely listen to multiple queues in azure functions, can you post your code?

Comment: The code I have posted is from function.json for my function. Imagine that the body of said function is just printing "Hello World", it shouldn't impact how configure the function settings.

Comment: If you're using C# and the Azure SDK when it's just a matter of creating a function per queue. I can post an example for you if you're using C# and the SDK.

Comment: Ah, sorry I understand now. I should have specified that I was using the Node.js version.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place the multiple Queues of Input bindings for the single Queue Trigger Function, but you can use the multiple output bindings for the same Queue Trigger Function.

[image]

[image]

I believe the function runs for single specified queue message not for the multiple queue messages at the same time using message array for the output binding object.

And we can also get the multiple messages from the same queue.

Refer to the SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48517716) and [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=javascript#bindings-code-examples) of Azure Functions Binding Samples for more information.